# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy' in Django although installed

Tags: python, django, pip, installation, moviepy

I have installed `MoviePy` within the virtual environment like this:

```
(env)$: sudo pip install ez_setup
Requirement already satisfied: ez_setup in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

(env)$: sudo pip install moviepy
Requirement already satisfied: moviepy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5.0,>=4.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: proglog<=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=2.8.1 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0,>=4.11.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: imageio<2.5,>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=2.8.1->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /home/ac3l1k/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from imageio<2.5,>=2.0->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio<2.5,>=2.0->moviepy)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from imageio<2.5,>=2.0->moviepy)
```

The installations are successful as you can see in the outputs above.
But when I use moviepy in my `models.py` of my Django project, then I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moviepy'
```

The command `pip freeze` gives me the following list of installed modules:

```
cffi==1.13.2
cryptography==2.8
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.7
django-extensions==2.2.5
django-filter==2.2.0
django-secure==1.0.1
django-sslserver==0.22
djangorestframework==3.10.3
ez-setup==0.9
Pillow==6.2.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pycparser==2.19
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.13.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

The `moviepy` module is not in the list. Why ?

Comment: Do you work with a virtual environment?

Comment: Please do *not* work with `sudo` when installing packages, this is a security vulnerability, work with the `--user` flag.

Comment: Yes, I am using a virtual environment. All the installations for my django project happens inside a virtual environmnt.

Comment: well if you prefix with `sudo` you run it in "another shell", hence the virtual environment is no longer "activated". Anyway, *never* use `sudo`.

Comment: sudo-ing will exit from your virtualenv

Answer (score 3):

You are using *`sudo`* when installing moviepy, it installs the packages as root, that's why pip is searching in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` folder.

With your environment (env) activated, ***don't use*** **`sudo`** to install moviepy and the package will be installed in your env.

Answer (score 3):

By prefixing the `pip install` with `sudo`, you run the installation in another environment, and thus you basically "deactivate" installing the package.

You thus should run this with:

```
(env)$: pip install moviepy
```

> **Note**: Please *never* use `sudo` when installing packages. By running it with `sudo`
>   you give the installation root access. If the package has malicious code in it,
>   you give it the possibility to make changes to the system. You can use
>   `pip3 install --user packagename` instead.